# MySQL query not working in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
String sqlInsertBeacon = "INSERT INTO `beacon` (zone_id, location) VALUE ('(SELECT id FROM zone WHERE GeographicalID = '" + geometry3 + "')', Point(" + x_coordinate + "," + y_coordinate + "))";
System.out.println("The SQL query is: " + sqlInsertBeacon);  // Echo for debugging
int countInserted3 = stmt.executeUpdate(sqlInsertBeacon);
System.out.println(countInserted3 + " records inserted.\n");
```

When I run the above code, the build is successful but the program stops when it reaches the execute line. I am entering using this sql query to insert data into a mysql database. I am not sure where the error is in my query? Can anyone suggest an alternative way or find the mistake?

The output of the program is this, as you can see the program, stops running after the second line:

> The SQL query is: INSERT INTO table
>   (zone_id, location)
>   VALUES
>   ((SELECT id FROM zone WHERE GeographicalID = '6311599'),  Point(-121.9453802,37.3256131) )
>   ;
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

For additional information incase it helps:

The stmt, is created like this:

```
 try (
            // Step 1: Allocate a database 'Connection' object
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/adhwere2?useSSL=false", "root", "your_new_password"); // MySQL

            // Step 2: Allocate a 'Statement' object in the Connection
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();) {
```

and the catch exception is :

```
} catch (SQLException ex) {

    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: Can you execute sqlInsertBeacon from some sql GUI client?

Comment: Add "S" to VALUE. VALUES!!

Comment: Are the `'` around the inner SELECT there for a reason?

Comment: The syntax of select query look totally incorrect

Comment: @Lino It is `MySQL` not `MSSQL`...

Comment: @sForSujit I am not getting any exception

Comment: @Lino I have entered point using 2 parameters in another table so thats not the problem

Comment: @MikeSuoto and adding S to Value didn't change anything.

Comment: you are certainly getting a exception, otherwise your program would not just "stop".

Comment: @sForSujit what part of the query is incorrect?

Comment: @luk2302 The terminal output shows :Build Successful and just stops

Comment: seems you have a trailing comma in your query, remove that

Comment: @lino still no luck

Comment: Show us more code. Where is `stmt` created, where are exceptions `catch`ed, etc...

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: can you show your `beacon`-Table, how many fields does it have? are some of them not null? we need to know all

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto thanks for reminding me, I printed out the stack trace and realised the problem was because my sub query is returning more than one result

Comment: Then use `LIMIT 1` in your sub select, this should solve the problem

Comment: @talex yes I just printed out the stack trace and realised the error was because the subquery was returning more than one result

Comment: @lino thanks , this has solved the problem

Comment: @Programmer i suggest you to use Usagi Miyamoto answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because the sub-query was returning more than one result, and printing out a stack trace helped debug this error. Using Limit 1 in the sub query also solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
String sqlInsertBeacon = "INSERT INTO `beacon` (zone_id, location)" +
  " VALUES ( (SELECT id FROM zone WHERE GeographicalID = '" + geometry3 + "'), Point(" +
  x_coordinate + "," + y_coordinate + "))";
```

Just removed the apostrophes aroung the inner `SELECT` and replaced `VALUE` with `VALUES`...

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't work, I edited my question to show the output

Answer (score 0):

please use query according to this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table
(column1, column2, ... )
VALUES
(expression1, expression2, ... ),
(expression1, expression2, ... ),
...;
```

your table name is in single quotes  and its VALUES  not value mind these small things

Comment: ` are not singe quotes

Comment: Those are no "single quotes" `'` but "backticks" `\``, a `MySQL` specific quote instead of the "double quotes" `"` of standard SQL

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this did not make it work

Answer (score 0):

Correct INSERT INTO SELECT statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

And you can use `PreparedStatement` to set parameters in your query.

Comment: the select in OPs question is a sub-select

Comment: So, his query can looks like this:
`INSERT INTO beacon(zone_id, location) 
SELECT id, Point(-121.9453802,37.3256131) FROM zone 
WHERE GeographicalID = '6311599';`